# Access vmware hosted website

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a web application running on an ubuntu vmware server, that is configured to be a NAT, I can access it via the host computer (the one that runs the vmware instance), but have no idea on how to access it from the outside world.

I tried using the host ip, such as: 84.111.111.111:3000 but to no avail (it runs on port 3000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inaccessible from the outside because your guest (vmware instance) is running on a separate network "behind" your host's IP address. This is, by definition, NAT. You have 2 options:

1. Port forwarding on the host. You can forward port 3000 on your host to your guest. You can do this using iptables or similar.
2. Use Bridge network configuration instead of NAT. In this case, the guest can be given an IP address that is on the same subnet as the host. Thus, the guest will be accessible like any other machine on the network.